# How can i get all the files that DO NOT start with "Something"?

Tags: vb.net, full-text-search, fileinfo

The line below fetches all files that start with *Cake*.

```
Dim fi As System.IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("Cake*")
```

How can i write the search pattern to get all the files, that do not start with Cake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be in C#, but it should get you close.

```
FileInfo fi[] = di.GetFiles();
var doNotFiles = fi.Where(file => !file.Name.StartsWith("Cake"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to give the VB.Net version (converted from @Daniel A. White's C# version) in case anyone else stumbles on this.

```
Dim FI = DI.GetFiles().Where(Function(f) Not f.Name.StartsWith("Cake"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You get all the files that start with something and use all that are not in that list and are in the original list?